# Remove all Columns Based on Error in Column Header?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I use index match or hlookup a lot to make sure I get only the columns I want for a certain file. Whatever I cannot match, I need to delete. What is the most efficient VBA script to remove all column headers of "#N/A"?

Comment: Loop over the headers from right to left, check for `IsError(cell.Value)` and delete if True

Comment: I tried the following but got error 424. Can you help me with this?

`
Sub del_err_colsG()
 Dim lastCol As Long, i As Integer
    lastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        For i = 1 To lastCol
            If Cells(1, i).IsError(cell.Value) Then Cells.EntireColumn.Delete
        Next
End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with an [xlCellType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) of **xlCellTypeFormulas** and specify **xlErrors** for the XlSpecialCellsValue  constant.

```
Sub del_err_cols()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        With .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
            .Cells.EntireColumn.Delete
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the shortest and best code to what I needed. Thanks, I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Jeeped solution is better, but since you posted code here's my suggestion:

```
Sub del_err_colsG() 

    Dim lastCol As Long, i As Integer 

    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 

    For i = lastCol To 1 Step -1
        If IsError(Cells(1, i).Value) Then Columns(i).Delete 
    Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I needed. The 1 Step -1 did it!